# Mod_rewrite matching both subdomain and query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

I'm currently mod_rewriting `domain.com/a/123/abc` to `page.php?this=123&that=abc` with:

```
RewriteRule ^a/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?this=$1&that=$2 [L]
```

Additionally I now want to mod_rewrite `a.domain.com/123/abc` to `page.php?this=123&that=abc`

So both `a.domain.com/123/abc` and `domain.com/a/123/abc` will redirect to `page.php?this=123&that=abc`

My problem is matching both the subdomain and the query string. This is what I've been working on but it's still not rewriting properly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.domain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /a/$1/$2 [L]
```

Note that wildcard domains are set up (*.domain.com). It is just the htaccess mod_rewriting that is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it the trailing `/` on your `RewriteCond`?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.domain\.com/
```

Should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.domain\.com
```

Comment: No, but removing it made no difference